# Dealing With Ajax Request Python

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, beautifulsoup

Case : 
I am trying to extract number of pages data from a site. I create a filter in the page with the below 
code:

```
 fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
 fp.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
 b = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
 b.get(url)
 time.sleep(10)
 search = b.find_element_by_name("rb")
 search.clear()
 search.send_keys('dove')
 search.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
 search.submit()
 shampoo_sel = b.find_element_by_id('flt-46')
 shampoo_sel.click()
 conditioner_sel = b.find_element_by_id('flt-47')
 conditioner_sel.click()
 time.sleep(5)
 search_url = b.current_url
 dp = urllib2.urlopen(search_url).read()
 dp_soup = BeautifulSoup(dp)
 search_page_num = dp_soup.find("li", { "id" : "pagContinue" })
 print search_page_num
```

while i try saving the code with the current URL ( both the URLs before and after the Filter is same and hence unable to get the exact number of pages after filter) 
what should I do in this case ???

Comment: So to clarify, you're trying to find how many pages of search data there are, after you've made two selections in what I assume is a search form?

Why are you scraping the page with urllib2?

Comment: Hi am more of an analyst than a programmer.. I am combining codes from different sources to get a output.. please do suggest if i can do something else :(

Comment: Please note what web site are you trying to scrape?

Comment: Well, Selenium is meant to operate a browser like a user does, so the best way to check the number of pages of results is to use the same thing a user does.

This is probably something like finding a piece of text on the page that indicates how many pages of results you have, which a user would see.  You'd do this on the page that's already open by your script.

What is the HTML of the element which a user sees, showing them the number of pages of search results?